# Programmatically import team project set

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way for a plug-in to import a Team Project Set file (.psf) into the current workspace? The corresponding interactive procedure is File -> Import -> Team Project Set.

Answer (score 5):

It is only possible (as far as I know) through internal classes. The class in charge of this import is `org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ProjectSetImportWizard`. The core of the importing process is `org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ImportProjectSetOperation`.

As a side note since I think this can be of interest, this information can be determined by going to the wizard (File > Import > Team > Team Project Set) then hitting <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. That will show you the class providing the wizard currently shown (in that case, `ProjectSetImportWizard`).